# Acts_as_taggable_on migration fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using Rails 3.0.6/Ruby 1.8.7 and I've been trying to get the acts_as_taggable_on (2.0.6) gem to work but it seems to fail on the default migration.
Log:

```
==  ActsAsTaggableOnMigration: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:tags)
   -> 0.3175s
-- create_table(:taggings)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't create table 'project_development.taggings' (errno: 150): 
CREATE TABLE `taggings` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
`tag_id` int(11), `taggable_id` int(11), `taggable_type` varchar(255), `tagger_id` 
int(11), `tagger_type` varchar(255), `context` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, 
FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`taggable_id`) REFERENCES 
`taggables` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`tagger_id`) REFERENCES `taggers`    (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

So it looks like the :polymorphic => true attribute does not work as intended. Google doesn't seem to be very helpful (similar bug reported eg http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/194219). Any way to fix it? Gem alternatives?

**SOLVED**
automatic_foreign_key conflicts with this gem

Comment: so how did you solve it? Did you stop using automatic_foreign_key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify the migration to add foreign key constraints?

The supplied migration in acts-as-taggable-on 2.0.6 looks like the following:

```
class ActsAsTaggableOnMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :tags do |t|
          t.column :name, :string
        end

        create_table :taggings do |t|
          t.column :tag_id, :integer
          t.column :taggable_id, :integer
          t.column :tagger_id, :integer
          t.column :tagger_type, :string

          # You should make sure that the column created is
          # long enough to store the required class names.
          t.column :taggable_type, :string
          t.column :context, :string

          t.column :created_at, :datetime
        end

        add_index :taggings, :tag_id
        add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context]
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :taggings
        drop_table :tags
      end
    end
```

Comment: Damn, I did not but one of the included gems indeed did.